# Java ME or Java SE (Raspberry Pi Zero)

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, java-me, raspberry-pi-zero

I want to write Java programs for the Raspberry Pi Zero (it has 512 MB RAM) and i don't know if i should choose the Java SE (Standard Edition) or the Java ME (Micro Edition).
Thanks for help

Comment: Java ME is for ancient phones (non-smart), it's effectively dead. Java SE is pretty much the only relevant edition. 512MB is plenty for simple Java programs.

Comment: Not true @JoachimSauer - It's true that JavaME 3.x was for MIDlet development. But JavaME 8 is for devices like Rasberry Pi. (And then there's also JavaME for office equipment, and TV-boxes / Blu-ray players). Which one to choose for Rasberry Pi depends on what you wanna do. I'm no expert on that field though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can spare the raspberry's resources I'd go with JavaSE. It is wider used and thus enjoys better support and tools.

In case you want to save resources check out JavaME as that is the main reason this thing exists.

What flavor does your OS install when you choose the java package?